# How to get rid of the values of infinity in the answer

Tags: r, logarithm

I solve the problem, and in logarithms I get 2 'infinity'. Therefore, I can not make a picture in the function after 'plot'.

`R` had trouble computing the model to the plot, since 2 out of 10 logit values (for CT of 9 and 10) were infinite. This is the same reason I was unable to compute the abline to the plot. However, even without the actual line, the relationship between the X variable and the logit looks fairly linear. Thus, the linearity condition is met, since the relationship between CT and the Logit function as depicted on the plot is close to linear.

Question:

> One of the key conditions for the validity of the simple logistic regression model is the assumption that the logit [loge(p/(1 – p)] is linearly related to X. Provide a graphical check of this condition for these data. What does the plot suggest?

So I decide:
In logistic regression, we assume a relationship between P(Y =1) and X of the form `p=P(Y=1)=e0+1X1+e0+1X`. This is equivalent to the model `L=loge(p1-p)=0+1CT`

In logistic regression we assume a linear relationship between `X` and the logit. Because our dataset is large enough, we can check this condition. Follow the next steps to check for this key condition:

**a.** To divide the CT into 10 intervals, named C, use the R codes:

```
> C<-numeric(699)

> C[biopsy$CT<=1]<-1

> C[biopsy$CT>1&biopsy$CT<=2]<-2

> C[biopsy$CT>2&biopsy$CT<=3]<-3

> C[biopsy$CT>3&biopsy$CT<=4]<-4

> C[biopsy$CT>4&biopsy$CT<=5]<-5

> C[biopsy$CT>5&biopsy$CT<=6]<-6

> C[biopsy$CT>6&biopsy$CT<=7]<-7

> C[biopsy$CT>7&biopsy$CT<=8]<-8

> C[biopsy$CT>8&biopsy$CT<=9]<-9

> C[biopsy$CT>9&biopsy$CT<=10]<-10

> tally(~C)
```

C

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10` 

145  50 108  80 130  34  23  46  14  69
```

There are 130 tumors with clump thickness values in the interval 5-6.

```
> tally(biopsy$Class~C)
```

C

```
biopsy$Class   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10

           0 142  46  96  68  85  16   1   4   0   0

           1   3   4  12  12  45  18  22  42  14  69
```

**b.** Of these 130 tumors with clump thickness in the interval 5-6, 85 were designated as benign and 45 were designated as malignant.

```
> p<-tally(biopsy$Class~C, format="proportion")

> p
```

C

```
biopsy$Class   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10

           0 142  46  96  68  85  16   1   4   0   0

           1   3   4  12  12  45  18  22  42  14  69

biopsy$Class      7          8          9         10

        0 0.04347826 0.08695652 0.00000000 0.00000000

        1 0.95652174 0.91304348 1.00000000 1.00000000
```

To get the proportion of malignant tumors in each of the CT groups, compute the following in R:

```
> p_hat<-p[2,]

> p_hat
```

Return:

```
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 

0.02068966 0.08000000 0.11111111 0.15000000 0.34615385 0.52941176 0.95652174 

         8          9         10 

0.91304348 1.00000000 1.00000000
```

Now, compute the 10 logit values with the R code:

```
> L_hat<-log(p_hat/(1-p_hat))

> L_hat
```

Return:

```
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 

-3.8572148 -2.4423470 -2.0794415 -1.7346011 -0.6359888  0.1177830  3.0910425 

         8          9         10 

 2.3513753        Inf        Inf
```

**c.** Compute the mean clump thickness in each CT group. Will be identical since the tumors were already grouped based on recorded clump thickness values:

```
> mean_CT<-mean(biopsy$CT~C)

> mean_CT
```

Return:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

**d.** `plot(L_hat~mean_CT,col="blue",main="Plot of Logits against CT means")`

[image: Output]

```
> model<-lm(L_hat~mean_CT)
```

Error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 

  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

> abline(model,col="red")
```

Warning message:

```
In abline(model, col = "red") :
```

I use only the first two of the 7 regression coefficients

Comment: Note that the problem is of your own making - you've arbitrarily binned the predictor to check for linearity. Use different bins; or, better, a non-parametric smooth through the observations.

Comment: @Scortchi uhm.. thank you! could  you please reveal your answer a little in terms of where exactly I need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the function $\hat{L}(p) = p / (1-p)$ and you are giving it inputs in the argument range $0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1$.  This function has the limiting value $\lim_{p \uparrow 1} \hat{L}(p) = \infty$, so it is not surprising that you get $\ln \hat{L}(1) = \infty$.  You are getting this output in your `R` code because that is the correct limiting value of the function with the argument value you are putting into it.

Luckily, this is not a problem for using logistic regression on your data.  Logistic regression models the data as Bernoulli outcomes (or binomial outcomes if they are aggregated) with an underlying probability function that follows the logit function.  This underlying functional form means that the model *does not allow zero probabilities or unit probabilities*, but it does allow observed binomial with sample proportions of zero or one.  Standard estimation methods may have trouble with this in some extreme cases, but usually the model can handle some of the sample proportions being zero or one (so long as this doesn't lead to estimated coefficients of negative or positive infinity).

In view of this, you should still be able to fit your data with a logistic regression, and use this to estimate the probabilities of outcomes based on the mean-CT explanatory variable.  In the groups where the sample proportion is one, the probability estimate should be close to one, but it won't be exactly equal to one.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I’ve seen several functions that would limit my range of values to the ones that could be depicted on the graph, but I am still confused as to how to compute it in R?

Comment: If this is real data about real sick people then I think your hospital/university should be providing you with proper training as lives are at stake. If it is self-study on a textbook then try searching this site for logistic regression.